# Superset to Elasticsearch Connection Error

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-superset

After executing `pip install elasticsearch-dbapi`, when I am trying to connect Superset to Elasticsearch, it gives the error:

> ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned was:\nCan't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:elasticsearch.http", "stacktrace": null}

Not sure the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue post the installation of `elasticsearch-dbapi`. Then I have restarted the instance, its started working fine.